# Range slider in Dialog with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm triying to use a RangeSlider widget to change a textView in a Dialog, but when in touch the button to the dialog the app crashes, I used the same logic in a normal activity and it works.
when I comment all the slider listener the dialog runs well

\

```
private fun startDialog(){
val dialog = Dialog(this)
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_startdialog)

      val testQuestionsDialog : TextView = findViewById(R.id.testQuestionsDialog)

       val questionsSlider : RangeSlider = findViewById(R.id.questionsSlider)
 
        questionsSlider.addOnChangeListener { _, value, _ ->
        var df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
        var result = df.format(value)
        testQuestionsDialog.text = "$value"}

      dialog.show()
  }
```

}

\

Comment: `the app crashes`, so you need to provide and check the crash stacktrace